# how to make custom alert in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to make custom alert in jquery mobile?I am able to make confirm in JQM.
http://jsfiddle.net/EELLj/31/
I need same type of alert having message with ok button as in jquery ?
A alert having "title", "message" and ok button ? can we make this custom alert.

```
function confirmDialog(text, callback) {
    var popupDialogId = 'popupDialog';
    $('<div data-role="popup" id="' + popupDialogId + '" data-confirmed="no" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:500px;"> \
                        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">\
                            <h1>Alert</h1>\
                        </div>\
                        <div role="main" class="ui-content">\
                            <h3 class="ui-title">' + text + '</h3>\
                            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b optionConfirm" data-rel="back">Yes</a>\
                            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b optionCancel" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">No</a>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>')
        .appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
    var popupDialogObj = $('#' + popupDialogId);
    popupDialogObj.trigger('create');
    popupDialogObj.popup({
        afterclose: function (event, ui) {
            popupDialogObj.find(".optionConfirm").first().off('click');
            var isConfirmed = popupDialogObj.attr('data-confirmed') === 'yes' ? true : false;
            $(event.target).remove();
            if (isConfirmed && callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
    popupDialogObj.popup('open');
    popupDialogObj.find(".optionConfirm").first().on('click', function () {
        popupDialogObj.attr('data-confirmed', 'yes');
    });
}


$('#testButton').on('click', function () {
    confirmDialog("Are you sure?", function(){
        alert('Confirmed');
    });
});
```

Comment: Take out the "No" button, change the caption of the "Yes" button to "OK" and simply close the dialog (or destroy it if you're creating a new one each time) when it's clicked.

Comment: Already try ..but giving error please check

Comment: Sure... http://jsfiddle.net/EELLj/33/

Comment: exactly great answer ..but I change your fiddle removing callback function .It is giving error http://jsfiddle.net/EELLj/34/

Comment: can we add "ok" button centre .after apply css

Comment: solved ..thanks for giving answer

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. Glad you got it sorted. You can center a button easily, I'm not going to write your code for you though - just pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: What if i want to make a confirm button return either true or false how will i do that?

Comment: Done every thing thanks for answering the Question